# XmlNodeReader in .NET for Windows Store app

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is it possible that there is no XmlNodeReader in windows store apps?
This isn't in the System.Xml namespace and there is no XmlTextReader neither.
What alternative tools do i have? I should consume a XML web api that simple:

```
var node = serviceClient.GetAllLeaguesAsync(apiKey);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(node));
```

Comment: what is return type of `GetAllLeaguesAsync()`?

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.Task<XElement>
but i can't even create a simple XmlNodeReader variable, so i don't think this is the poin :S

Comment: yes, as far as I can see, there is no XmlNodeReader or XmlTextReader. If the goal is to convert `XElement` to `XDocument` you can try without XmlNodeReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment, if your goal is to convert `XElement` to `XDocument`, you can try without `XmlNodeReader`. For example :

```
var node = await serviceClient.GetAllLeaguesAsync(apiKey);
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc.AddFirst(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [IXmlNode Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.ixmlnode)?